# visual studio 2012 open files disappear

Tags: .net, ide, visual-studio-2012

When I am working in Visual Studio 2012 and debugging, making changes, and debugging after a while, eventually my open documents disappear. They are still open, apparently (I'd add a screenshot but I can't yet), but going to Window > (a file) and trying to select it does nothing. I have to choose Close All Documents (fine if there's only one or two - but the very next time I debug I'm back to the same state) or restart the application. Is anyone else experiencing this? I'm wondering if it's an extension that is causing the problem.

Installed extensions:

- Advanced Installer 9.6.1
- Microsoft Web Developer Tools NuGet Package
- Manager Productivity Power Tools
- Spell Checker
- Team Foundation Server Power Tools 2012
- Telerik WebUI VSExtensions
- Telerik Windows Phone VSExtensions
- Telerik WinForms VSEXtensions
- TFS Pocess Template Editor
- TFS Team Collaboration
- TFS Work Item Type Designer
- Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor
- Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript
- VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012 Web Essentials 2012
- ReSharper 7.1.1

Comment: The only time I've encountered something like this was with an add-in/extension.  Really, the only thing you can do is remove one extension at at time (restart VS) and see if the problem goes away.  I use Resharper 7.1.1, Nuget, VSCommand for Visual Studio, and Productivity Power Tools, and don't have the aforementioned problem--so, maybe you can save those to uninstall last.

Comment: I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2013 SP3, and not necessarily with .NET, but debugging any kind of file. The "Close all Documents" option is the first workaround I've come across that actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012 (early access release). I uninstalled it and stopped having the problem, then reinstalled it and the problem came back. I don't know if it is conflicting with another add-in, but I'll leave it uninstalled for now.

Comment: Do you have linked files in your solution? If yes then consider disabling "Smart Linked File Navigation" from Tools, VSCommands, Options, IDE Enhancements, Solution Explorer

Comment: Yes, I do. I reinstalled that add-in and disabled that, and so far I haven't had the problem again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I didn't have VSCommands.
Instead, I removed a couple of VS 2010 (yes 2010) components recently installed.
For now, everything seems to work.
(There might be some versioning confusion, so 2012 picked some wrong 2010 components. Just a guess...)

Comment: I currently have this problem with visual studio 2013.I don't have VSComands installed. On the other hand, I have VS2012 installed and it does not contain same issue. Anyone fix this on VS2013?